# Definition of a graded ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

In Matsumura's commutative ring theory book he says that if R is ring graded by an abelian semigroup then $R_0$ is a subring. In particular he states that $1\in R_0$. But this seems wrong if we just take the product of rings. For example $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ graded (as a multiplicative semigroup) but the identity {1,1} is in both components of the grading. So my question is in a grading do we require that $R_gR_h\neq 0$?

Comment: What is your $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ grading on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Sorry I edited it to be more clear that I was considering the multiplicative structure on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let $R_1$ and $R_0$ be either of the two components of the direct sum. So since it is a direct sum of rings $R_1R_1\subset R_1$ and $R_0R_0\subset R_0$ and $R_0R_1=0\in R_0$ so this respects grading.

Comment: It's as a multiplicative semigroup so 1*1 not 1+1